# Is there any short way in my current method of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet code below. For me I think this is a long method. Is there any short method for this? Thanks

```js
var aaa = '1:00 AM'
var bbb = aaa.split(" ");
var ccc = bbb[0],
    ddd = bbb[1];
$("#time").val(ddd);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="textbox" id = "time">
```

Comment: do you need to use aaa or bbb or ccc anywhere else in the code?

Comment: `$('#time').val(aaa.split(' ')[1]);`

Comment: Just get rid of the variables, and name your variables more descriptively...

Comment: I would've said `$('#time').val('AM');`

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't need it if there is a short way.

Comment: @AndrewL. if you get rid of them, what would you name them? :p

Comment: @JaromandaX That won't be dynamic.

Comment: Since I love your name, here's another cool way.. `aaa.match(/[AMP]+/g)[0]`

Comment: @Tushar - neither is the code in the question

Comment: @AndrewL. - it's OK, was having a bit of fun, hence the :p

Comment: I just realized that @JaromandaX should win this already :P.. I can't think of any shorter than that..

Comment: @AndrewL. about the variables sorry for that I just testing and naming it any variables :) And for Tushar thanks is working :).. For Choz I will try it next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, better variable names would greatly help future developers. `aaa` carries almost no meaning.

Secondly, just make your expressions more direct. Save variables for when you need to break your code into smaller chunks:

```
var time = '1:00 AM'.split(" ");
var hour = time[0],
    twelve_hour_suffix = time[1];
$("#time").val(twelve_hour_suffix);
```

There are a lot of ways to make it shorter (even single-liners), but I feel this is sufficiently small and direct that readers will understand it easily.

Comment: _future debuggers_ that's funny. I've seen future coders/developers till now.

Comment: @Tushar ^^ Fair enough. For small functions like this, debugging is usually when I want descriptive variables. Annoying, but not difficult to read and refactor this as a coder. I'll make the change anyway.

Comment: @Aaron3468 and Tushar I love the way your code :). Thanks